# React useRef() is null and is not null at the same time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, google-chrome-devtools, react-dom

I've come across an interesting issue, I'm trying to assign a ref to a `<div>`, so I have a `useRef()` and I put it on my `<div`. My goal is that once I call a specific function I'll have the reference to mimic `.click()` on that div. Now, when I call that function it doesn't work, the ref is *null*, so I `console.log(divRef)` and what I see in devtools is the following:

[image]

I see that on my ref, current is *null* but inside there's also the reference to my div? I can't access that div reference, even though when I see it's properties I can confirm that it's indeed the div that I want to reference.

Further investigating, on devtools I right click and choose 'Save as global variable' to see what happens, and now I get the ref correctly, with `current: div`, just to make sure, I use the global variable to mimic the `.click()` behavior and it does work! I just saved the same object, but somehow now is not *null* on devtools.

[image]

How come when I log my ref, I can *see* my div being returned but I can't access it, somehow is null and not null at the same time? Again, my goal is to be able to access the reference on a function call so I can mimic `.click()`

PD: I know images are discouraged, but I really wanted to share what I'm looking at in devtools, that is, that the object is null but also has the correct references inside of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is null and is not null at the same time?

No. its dev tools evaluation of that object, if you hover your mouse over that blue `i` icon it will tell you values are evaluated just now. since the object reference it is logging is the same as the time it created when it was null; it you really want to see what is contained in an object in a specific point time you should log its `JSON.stringify()` value ( or deep copy and log the copied version ).

that `ref` was empty when it created and `current` will be assigned after first re-render so this will happen;